Next.js logging behaviour in production
I have an issue which I cannot figure out.
I'm using console.log. In production the log works only in top level module, but not inside a function.
In dev it works everywhere.
Example:
console.log("tady1");

export default function getData() {

  console.log("tady2");

  return {key: 1};

}

When I call the function getData in production the log statemant that prints "tady2" is not executed, but the first one (which prints "tady1" is.
In dev mode both are executed.
I have
compiler: {
  removeConsole: false,
  }

next configuration.
Here is a minimal example https://github.com/jira-zz/next-logging-test

I would recommend to use winston for safe logging. Or try to use if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production').
